# fetch any data that contain ID core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest, swift3

How I fetch these datas

[Account1, Account3]

in

[Account1, Account2, Account3, Account4, ..] (id entity)

with account1 & account3 id

I tried this below code, but it got some random account, not specific to account 1 and account 3.

```
        var ids = [account1id, account3id]

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Accounts> =  Accounts.fetchRequest()
        let titleSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "type", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [titleSort]
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY %@ IN id", argumentArray: ids)

        var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<Accounts>
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: contexts, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        }


        do {

            try controller.performFetch()
            let tes = controller.fetchedObjects!
            print("check: \(tes.count) \(tes)")

        } catch {

            let error = error as NSError
            print("\(error)")

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ids = [id1, id2]
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY %K IN %@", 
                                   argumentArray: [id, ids])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ANY` in your predicate as you aren't using a to-many relationship. Your `IN` is also the wrong way round. It should be:

```
NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", argumentArray: ids)
```

Comment: It's `NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", ids)`. Without *argumentArray*.